# How to download programmatically a module?

Tags: 7, files

I need to programmatically download projects from drupal.org, and then eventually enable it with [`modules_enable`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!module.inc/function/module_enable/7). Anyone knows how to do it?

Here's the final solution :
I'm sharing the code i used for those who'll face the same problem.

```
    /**
     * 
     * Function downloading the last version of the module in MY_MODULE_MODULE_DIRECTORY
     * $modulename correspond au nom system du module
     *
     * @param string $modulename
     */
    function MY_MODULE_download_module($modulename) {
      // DEBUT CODE TELECHARGEMENT

      $base_url = 'http://updates.drupal.org/release-history/' . $modulename . '/7.x';
      // @TODO MODULE NAME

      $xml = drupal_http_request($base_url);
      if (!isset($xml->error) && isset($xml->data)) {
        $data = $xml->data;
      }
      try {
        $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($data);
      }
      catch (Exception $e) {
        // SimpleXMLElement::__construct produces an E_WARNING error message for
        // each error found in the XML data and throws an exception if errors
        // were detected. Catch any exception and return failure (NULL).
        return;
      }
      $json = json_encode($xml);
      $array = json_decode($json, TRUE);
      $download_link = $array['releases']['release'][0]['download_link'];

      $path = MY_MODULE_contrib_dowload($download_link);
      MY_MODULE_archive_extract($path, MY_MODULE_MODULE_DIRECTORY);

      // FIN CODE TELECHARGEMENT
    }

    /**
     * Fonction downloading a file
     * Inspired from update_manager_file_get($url).
     * Upload the file in the temporary folder
     *
     * @param url $url
     */
    function MY_MODULE_contrib_dowload($url) {
      $parsed_url = parse_url($url);
      $remote_schemes = array(
        'http',
        'https',
        'ftp',
        'ftps',
        'smb',
        'nfs'
      );
      if (!in_array($parsed_url['scheme'], $remote_schemes)) {
        // This is a local file, just return the path.
        return drupal_realpath($url);
      }

      $cache_directory = _update_manager_cache_directory();
      $local = $cache_directory . '/' . drupal_basename($parsed_url['path']);
      // load the file in the right directory

      return system_retrieve_file($url, $local, FALSE, FILE_EXISTS_REPLACE);
    }

    /**
     * Function inspired from update_manager_archive_extract($file, $directory)
     * extracts a file to a directory
     *
     * @param path_to_file $file
     * @param path_to_directory $directory
     * @throws Exception
     * @return A path
     */
    function MY_MODULE_archive_extract($file, $directory) {
      $archiver = archiver_get_archiver($file);
      if (!$archiver) {
        throw new Exception(t('Cannot extract %file, not a valid archive.', array(
          '%file' => $file
        )));
      }

      // Remove the directory if it exists, otherwise it might contain a mixture of
      // old files mixed with the new files (e.g. in cases where files were removed
      // from a later release).
      $files = $archiver->listContents();

      // Unfortunately, we can only use the directory name to determine the project
      // name. Some archivers list the first file as the directory (i.e., MODULE/)
      // and others list an actual file (i.e., MODULE/README.TXT).
      $project = strtok($files[0], '/\\');

      $extract_location = $directory . '/' . $project;
      if (file_exists($extract_location)) {
        file_unmanaged_delete_recursive($extract_location);
      }

      $archiver->extract($directory);
      return $archiver;
    }
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Normally you want to use [`drush`](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush), e.g.

```
drush -y en module_name
```

which would download, install and enable your module of interest.

Check `drush.api.php` to use appropriate API hooks which could be useful.

If you don't want to use Drush, check how Update Manager does that in [`update/update.manager.inc`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21update%21update.manager.inc/7), e.g.

- [`update_manager_file_get`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!update!update.manager.inc/function/update_manager_file_get/7)
- [`update_manager_archive_extract`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!update!update.manager.inc/function/update_manager_archive_extract/7)
- etc.

To get the list of available files to download for specific project you've to fetch and parse the release history which is available at:

```
https://updates.drupal.org/release-history/project_name/7.x
```

the same as drush does that (check by `drush -vd dl foo`) and get the links from there.

Answer (score 2):

With drupal 8 I fell in love with [drupal console](http://drupalconsole.com).

The output is much clearer and it provides you with suggestion (and sometimes completion) on the arguments.

To download a module using console the long command is: `drupal module:download module_name`
and the short command is: `drupal m:download module_name`

Console provides you with the downloadable versions of that module and asks you which you want to download.

To install a module using console the long command is: `drupal module:install module_name`. and the short command is `drupal m:i`