# How do I configure SSO by SAML?

Tags: 7, users

At first, I am new in SAML. Could somebody tell step by step, how to configure SSO on Drupal using simplesamlphp? Or how to test by "Test configured authentication sources"?

What I have now.

1. Installed [simpleSAMLphp Authentication](https://www.drupal.org/project/simplesamlphp_auth) module.
2. Add simplesamlphp library to my site (mysite/simplesamlphp).
3. Changed config.php
4. Added meta to saml20-sp-remote.php

   $metadata['name'] = array(
   'SingleSignOnService'  => 'url_login',
   'SingleLogoutService'  => 'url_logout',
   'certFingerprint'      => 'key',
   );
5. When I go to mysite/saml_login, I am return to login page on IdP. After login I return to my site (mysite/sso/login?params) with SAMLRequest and other GET-params. But site show page not fount error. On [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_Assertion_Markup_Language) it step 2.

So what I did wrong? May be I must set same page callback to handle this GET-params?

I also try to did this by simplesaml "Test configured authentication sources", but I got the same result.

Please, help!

Comment: Maybe [this bug](https://www.drupal.org/node/2044385)? That module is in alpha so don't expect it to be fully functional yet...

Comment: @Clive It sems, sth other :(

Comment: @Clive I think you may be mistaken with *yet*. Last update to dev is marked as 2013-Oct-01, and [as we already know](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/87749/16495) actual date must have been earlier. Looks like module development is staled.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very old question but worth solving it.

By:

> I also try to did this by **simplesaml** "Test configured authentication sources", but I got the same result.

It seems that @misha-from-lviv didn't configure simpleSAMLphp correctly.

> $metadata['name'] = array( 'SingleSignOnService' => 'url_login', 'SingleLogoutService' => 'url_logout', 'certFingerprint' => 'key', );

The metadata is incomplete

The process to configure the simplesamlphp is way more complex that the 5 steps described there. [This Vagrant box](https://github.com/AngelAlvarado/continuous-delivery-saml-sso/releases/tag/1.1.SSO.2) setup simplesAMLphp (as an SP and IdP) and Drupal 7 for you and let's you start testing SAML right away.

Disclaimer: I created the [box](http://www.molanco.com/blog/en/simplesamlphp-saml-20-sso-single-sing-setting-local-sp-idp)